# Переход с tableViewController в header collectionViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

Всем привет. Помогите решить.
Задача передать name с помощью или без `button` из `tableViewController` в `header` из `collectionViewController`. 
Понимаю что у меня переменная принимает `nil`, но где принимает и как исправить уже голову сломал и справиться не могу. Я новичек, поэтому не судите строго.
Вот код:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

var file: File!

var files: [File] = [File(name: "name1", address: "address1", image: ""), File(name: "name2", address: "address2", image: "")]

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let dvc = segue.destination as? CollectionViewController {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
        if indexPath == nil {
            dvc.files2 = files[indexPath!]
        } else {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}


class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var files2: File!

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath) as! Header

    header.nameLabel.text = files2!.name
    header.addressLabel.text = "address"

    return header
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
class ViewController2: UITableViewController {

   var file: File!
   var files: [File] = [File(name: "name1", address: "address1", image: ""), File(name: "name2", address: "address2", image: "")]

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if let dvc = segue.destination as? CollectionViewController {
         if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let row = indexPath.row
            assert(row < files.count)
            dvc.file2 = files[row]
         }
      } else {
         print("error")
      }
   }

   // ...

}

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

   var file2: File?

   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

      if let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath) as? Header, let file = self.file2 {
         header.nameLabel.text = file.name
         header.addressLabel.text = file.address
         return header
      } else {
         return UICollectionReusableView()
      }

   }

   // ...

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не получилось((